# Install python pywin32 in WINE?

Tags: installation, python, wine

I'm trying to install python under WINE in order to run and communicate with a windows application that uses COM.

I've tried the following but neither seems to work:

```
[root@localhost ForCentOS]# wine msiexec /i python-2.7.2.msi
fixme:msi:MSI_OpenDatabaseW open failed r = 80030050 for L"C:\\windows\\temp\\msifc.tmp"
[root@localhost ForCentOS]#


[root@localhost ForCentOS]# wine start python-2.7.2.msi
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000500
--> this hangs and does not return...
```

Comment: Wouldn't python for linux work for you?

Comment: There're certain cases when you need this. For example, if you need to run win32com under Linux.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me tested in Debian 8.

**Wine installation**

```
apt-get install wine
dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install wine32
```

**Python2.7 Installation**

Download the latest Python from your fav source and install it using:

```
wine msiexec /i ~/src/python-2.7.10.msi
```

**win32com for Python**

Download from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/
and install it using:

```
wine ~/src/pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe
```